# Regex for capturing software versions

Tags: python, regex

I am dealing with the versions of certain software packages in a `for loop` and I have used the following regex to capture just the numbers and exclude the text part of a version.

```
regex = r'[0-9][,-_\.\d]*(,\d+)?/i'
```

Although the above regex works fine on `regex101.com` for the following versions:

```
binutils-112.16.91
bison-2.1
bogl-0.1.18-1.4
bogl-0.1.18_1.4
bogl-0.1-18_1.4
5.2
mod_ruby-1.2.4
2.0.0-1.00-r5_i586
bogl-0.1-18_1,4.4
```

The expected output from the above versions individually is:

```
112.16.91
2.1
0.1.18-1.4
0.1.18_1.4
0.1-18_1.4
5.2
1.2.4
2.0.0-1.00-r5_i586
0.1-18_1,4.4
```

But it returns empty match in Python. Could someone explain why this might be happening? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the expected output for clarity. Also `/i` should be replaced with `flags=re.I`

Comment: provide an example of how you are using the pattern

Comment: @mozway I have specified the expected output in my question. Thanks!

Comment: You  should remove the `/i` indeed, then you will also have partial matches. You could try something like `\b\d[\w,.-]*` with re.search per line, or use re.findall instead of a loop to find all matches https://regex101.com/r/fSOiq4/1

Comment: I'd start with `\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?([-_].*)?` for SemVer + optional release tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part `/i` is not the notation in Python for a case insensitive pattern, it would be a flag `re.I` But note that as you are not matching any case sensitive characters, you don't need that flag at all.

Apart from that, your pattern would have [partial matches](https://regex101.com/r/tmG4zH/1) instead of a full match as you can see in the demo link.

For the given examples, you can start the match with a word boundary and a digit, followed by optional repetitions of all allowed characters.

If you want to have multiple matches, instead of looping manually you can use re.findall to return all the matches in a list.

```
\b\d[\w,.-]*
```

A bit more specific, matching at least a single dot between digits and optionally match one of `_` `.` `,` `-` followed by 1+ word characters:

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?:[_.,-]\w+)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c9JquZ/1)

Answer (score 1):

Kinda sketchy as if one package contains a number, the output will be wrong but otherwise, it works on your example

```
original = ['binutils-112.16.91',
 'bison-2.1',
 'bogl-0.1.18-1.4',
 'bogl-0.1.18_1.4',
 'bogl-0.1-18_1.4',
 '5.2',
 'mod_ruby-1.2.4',
 '2.0.0-1.00-r5_i586',
 'bogl-0.1-18_1,4.4']


individual_versions = []
for package in original:
    for char_index, char in enumerate(package): 
        if char.isdigit():
            individual_versions.append(package[char_index:])
            break
```

Comment: Right. This wouldn't work for tools like `dos2unix` or `2to3` or `python3-3.10` (3.10 is the correct version), for example.